# GCP PUB/SUB allow different projects to publish to a topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Lets say there are Projects A, B and C. I have created a topic "my-topic" in project A. Now I want the project B and C to publish some data onto the topic "my-topic". Ideally, I want to publish the log data of project B and C onto the topic created in project A. Can this be even possible?

Comment: When you say you want to publish the log of data of project B and C onto the topic created in project A, are you talking specifically about [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#pubsub-overview) data or do you mean you want to publish some arbitrary data to the topic from, for example, GCE instances running Projects B and C?

Comment: only cloud logging data

Comment: In summary, you want to aggregate all the logs in the same project, right?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, yes exactly

Answer (score 6):

Give `roles/pubsub.publisher` role to the Topic in Project A to the service accounts of Project B and C.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this in different manner.

Firstly, the logs have project boundaries. You can't view the logs in one place for all projects.

However you can export the logs (perform a custom/advance query to get only the relevant log lines) in a common place with [the sinks](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/aggregated_sinks#gcloud).

- Sink the logs into BigQuery to perform request and find insight in them
- Sink the logs in PubSub for real time processing
- Sing the logs into CLoud Storage file, for (legal) archiving
- Sink the logs into CLoud Storage or Splunk for an external usage and ingestion.

Is it enough for you?

Comment: thank you for detailed answer. This information helps me a lot